# datatype of items in listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

i am using the list box to store the input from user.
is there is any way to find the type of the item in the listbox, means to say that i want to find the type of item in the listbox whether the item is string type or int type.
is there is any way to do so. if yes please let me know...
i am using code below to iterate through the items in listbox:

```
 foreach (ListItem item in ListBox2.Items)
            {

                value = temp + item;
                temp = value + "," ;
            }
```

thanks..

Comment: How does the user input the data?

Comment: user input the data through textbox

Answer (score 2):

In general, users will input data into text fields and other controls - if the control exposes the data as a specific data type (say Dates for a calendar control) then you already have the information.

If it is text, you will need to try and parse the data to a specific type and if it parses, assume it is of that type. This is not foolproof, as a specific piece of text might be parseable to a number of different data types.

The different basic types in the BCL have `TryParse` methods on them that will return `true` if parsing was successful. Look at the MSDN documentation for [int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx), [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), [bool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx) etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about actual hard types, you could use typeof(value). Otherwise if you've got strings, but some of them represent ints, Int32.TryParse(value, output), and if it returns false then you've got a string.